# multi layered mysql call within php

Tags: php, mysql

hope you're all looking forward to the weekend. :)

I have a slight organisational rearrangement problem with some php/mysql. I have the following piece of code which works perfectly well:

```
// Get the regions our user is assigned to look after
$result1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM regions WHERE staff_100_id='$id'");
while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {

    // Now get the claims that have come in for the above regions.
    $result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM registrar_claims WHERE reg_region='$row1[region]' && ready_to_process='yes' ORDER BY claim_id ASC");
    while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {

        echo $row2[claim_id] ." ";
        echo $row2[reg_1st_name] ." ";
        echo $row2[reg_2nd_name] ."<br>";

        }
    }
}
```

The output of this is something like:

```
2 Roger Ramjet
7 Snobby Bobgrass
5 Num Nut
6 Phil Pott
```

I'd like to have the output come out so that it is arranged by claim_id in respect overall, not just as per cycle within the db calls. So I want the output to become:

```
2 Roger Ramjet
5 Num Nut
6 Phil Pott
7 Snobby Bobgrass
```

Would someone be willing to show me how to rearrange things to achieve this?

Thank you, very much appreciated! :)

Cass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

regionI hope you are escaping your query entries :)

What I would do is compact the queries by using a subquery

```
SELECT * 
FROM registrar_claims 
WHERE reg_region IN (SELECT region FROM regions WHERE staff_100_id='$id') 
   AND ready_to_process='yes'
ORDER BY claim_id ASC
```

That should yield the desired ordered results

Comment: Yeah, I missed that. Changed my answer

Comment: Thank you Machavity - I have tied your answer and it has worked perfectly for me. Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could `JOIN` the two tables and do the whole thing in one query.

```
SELECT *
FROM regions JOIN registrar_claims 
ON registrar_claims.region_id=regions.region 
WHERE regions.staff_100_id='$id' && registrar_claims.ready_to_process='yes' 
ORDER BY registrar_claims.claim_id ASC
```

Comment: Hi weltraumpirat, thanks for the answer. I like this solution but have done with another that works as well. I might swap to this one though, it appeals to me! Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
<?
// Get the regions our user is assigned to look after and all the claims that have come in 
//for the above regions.

$query = 
    "SELECT 
        regions.*,
        registrar_claims.*
    FROM 
        regions inner join registrar_claims on registrar_claims.reg_region = regions.region
    WHERE 
        regions.staff_100_id='$id' and
        registrar_claims.ready_to_process = 'yes'
    ORDER BY
        registrar_claims.claim_id";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con, $query))) {
        echo $row[claim_id] ." ";
        echo $row[reg_1st_name] ." ";
        echo $row[reg_2nd_name] ."<br>";
}
?>
```

Plus I would advise looking at prepared statements for the security and clarity of your code.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin, your help is appreciated! I've used Machavity's answer below as it's nice and easy at least to my mind! But your answer is appreciated also. :)

Comment: I plan to use prepared statements more as soon as I can get my head around them better. I'm kinda struggling with it all at the moment but will get better in a little time. Thanks.